# MPAndroidChart adding setData compiler error

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to create a line graph using MPAndroidChart.  I have looked at many examples online and they all seem to suggest that you add data to a chart like this:

```
    LineChart graph = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);

    // creating list of entry
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new Entry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new Entry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new Entry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new Entry(2f, 3));
    entries.add(new Entry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new Entry(9f, 5));

    // creating labels
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");

    graph.setData(entries, labels);
```

But I get a compiler error on setData saying:

> setData (com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData) in Chart cannot
>   be applied to
>   (java.util.ArrayList,
>   java.util.ArrayList)

I can fix the compiler error by changing my code to:

```
LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);

graph.setData(lineData);
```

But then I get this run time error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.ebucher.lisa, PID: 11365
>                                                                     java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2
>                                                                         at com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer.generateTransformedValuesLine(Transformer.java:181)
>                                                                         at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer.drawValues(LineChartRenderer.java:570)
>                                                                         at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:272)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17469)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16464)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17238)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16464)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17238)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16459)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17238)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
>                                                                         at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1373)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16459)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17238)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16459)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17238)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16459)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17238)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16459)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17238)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16459)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17238)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3205)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16464)
>                                                                         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:325)
>                                                                         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:331)
>                                                                         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:366)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3134)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2933)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2522)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
>                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
>                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
>                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
>                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

I get the same errors when I try to create a bar graph instead of a line graph.

Comment: Try: LineData lineData = new LineData(labels, dataSet);

Comment: @Guardanis LineData
(com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet...)
in LineData cannot be applied
to
(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>,
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet)

Comment: Strange, it's definitely available in v2.2.5

Comment: @Guardanis I am using "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1" I will try using 2.2.5 instead.

Comment: @Guardanis i have the same problem using the beta

Comment: Have you tried sorting the entries by x-index? Also, please note that in version 3.0.0 the first paramater of `Entry` is the x-value, and the second one is the y-value, so chances are you'll want to switch the order of your `Entry` intialization, so it's e.g. `new Entry(0, 4f);`.

Comment: Using v2.2.5 worked for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try downgrading the dependency to:**

```
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with version `3.0.0-beta1` the `Entry` constructors have changed to `Entry(float x, float y)` so you'll have to first pass the x-index and then the corresponding y-value. Even though this breaks backwards compatibility it feels more natural now that `float` x-values are supported.

So you should change your code to this:

```
LineChart graph = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);

// creating list of entry
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new Entry(0, 4f));
entries.add(new Entry(1, 8f));
entries.add(new Entry(2, 6f));
entries.add(new Entry(3, 2f));
entries.add(new Entry(4, 18f));
entries.add(new Entry(5, 9f));

LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);

graph.setData(lineData);
```

Also, in order to do rendering optimizations the entries have to be sorted by x-value, which might be why your chart is crashing (since you've switched x- and y-values in your entries). The fixed code above is already properly sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because you have **unsorted values** (not sorted by x-position). You can fix doing:

```
List<Entry> entries = ...;
Collections.sort(entries, new EntryXComparator());
```

Also [check the documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data#the-order-of-entries) for more information on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this error too.

I just found a method of avoid error.

List can't store index more than 6.
You try list store index less than 5.

Example:

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new Entry(4f, 0));
entries.add(new Entry(8f, 1));
entries.add(new Entry(6f, 2));
entries.add(new Entry(2f, 3));
entries.add(new Entry(18f, 4));

// creating labels
ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
labels.add("January");
labels.add("February");
labels.add("March");
labels.add("April");
labels.add("May");
```

But application sometimes finish and get NegativeArraySizeException:-2.

When you try list store index less than 4.

I think this error is v3.0.0-beta1's bug.

Sorry for my poor English.
I hope you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding LinedataSet object to setDate instead of List of LinedataSet objects

Refer below code

```
LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSetList = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
            dataSets.add(dataSet ); // add the datasets
LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSetList);

graph.setData(lineData);
```